# How to calculate week number in hive or python? The week should run from Saturday to Friday

Tags: python, hive, hiveql

I have tried the following:
Select weekofyear(current_timestamp)
But this calculates the week from Monday to Sunday. I want the week from Saturday to Friday, based on that it should populate week number.
In hive if we can't do, how about in python.?

In python I tried:

```py
A = datetime.date(2020, 3, 29).isocalendar()[1]
```

But again this calculates the week from Monday to Saturday

Comment: Why don't you just add an offset?

Comment: New bee to python.. how to apply offset ?

Comment: if the current day is Saturday or Sunday, add 1 to the result?

Comment: You need to define how to calculate the week number of the first day of the year. From Python manual, on how the Gregorian calendar works:
"The ISO year consists of 52 or 53 full weeks, and where a week starts on a Monday and ends on a Sunday. The first week of an ISO year is the first (Gregorian) calendar week of a year containing a Thursday. This is called week number 1, and the ISO year of that Thursday is the same as its Gregorian year."

Answer (score 1):

One more try, with assuming that jan 1 is always on week 1.

```
from datetime import date
from calendar


def week_number(ndate, week_start=calendar.MONDAY):
    new_years_day = ndate.replace(month=1, day=1)
    offset = (new_years_day.weekday() - week_start) % 7  # Count back to start of week. Modulo for positive value.
    all_days = (ndate - new_years_day).days + offset  # Days ago week 1 started.

    return (all_days // 7) + 1  # Integer division means we don't have to floor() it. Add 1 for human readable numbers.


print(week_number(date(2020, 1, 1)))  # 1, always
print(week_number(date(2020, 3, 29)))  # 13
print(week_number(date(2020, 3, 29), calendar.SATURDAY))  # 14
print(week_number(date(2020, 3, 27), calendar.SATURDAY))  # 13
```

Comment: I think you should add 1, not substract 1, right? Also, you don't account for the very beginning of the year which could actually become the last week of the previous year if offset in a certain manner.

Comment: Actually, starting the week earlier means that you will potentially have a lower week number. But yeah, the previous year week num might be a problem. For example, get_week_number(date(2016,1,1)) will return 53. Different week number systems handle that differently, so it needs a clearer definition than we have here I think.

Comment: Didn't work anything like I was thinking. It's very interesting, and needs quite a bit of thinking. Most of all, you need a very clear definition of how to decide what week the first day of the year is. I think I found 3 different methods for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

def week_number(ndate):
    odate = datetime.datetime(ndate.year, 1, 1) 
    spec = odate.weekday()
    alldays =    (ndate - odate).days + spec - 4

    mod = alldays % 7
    days = (alldays - mod) / 7

    if (mod > 0):
        days = days + 1

    return (int)days

print(week_number(datetime.datetime.today()))
```

Comment: I'm note sure to understand how that snippet is supposed to calculate a week number between 1 and 51 if you use `% 7`

Comment: No its not working. It's giving week number 4 for the date 01/01/2020

Comment: I updated my answer with code inspired by this answer, instead of my earlier failed attempt. Pretty happy with that one.